# Dynamic HTML Form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like an HTML form that has a few fixed inputs, as well as some dynamic ones that are selected based on an a drop-down.  My goals:

1. I would prefer this is entirely handled in the browser, rather than AJAX calls to fetch the dynamic "sub-form" portions that were selected by the drop-down.
2. Rather than adding a 3rd party JS library, I would like to leverage the libraries that come with ASP.NET MVC4 (jquery, knockout, etc.).  However, I am willing to add a 3rd party library if the former attempt is too clumsy.

What path do you recommend?  Does HTML5 have any "help" for this?

**Update**
It occurs to me that the HttpPost of the form should not include "sub-form" values that were not chosen in the select box.  What now?  Store the extra div elements in an out-of-document list and swap them in as needed?  **Or perhaps much better**, have an event attached to the submit button that deletes the unused/invisible divs before posting?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say `.. as well as some dynamic ones that are "selected" ..` Do you mean ones that are dynamically inserted into the DOM based on the drop down selection?

Comment: @Matthew: The "selected" items could be dynamically inserted into the DOM, or hidden/unhidden as dtbarne shared in his answer.  Perhaps there are one or two other ways?  I'm also curious how knockout could participate, or if it would be overkill.

Comment: Always love playing in knockout. It's never overkill :) I added an example of how to do it.

Comment: I would also choose knockout in this case as it seems the most appropriate tool. jQuery, as others have shown, can also solve this elegantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure javascript is perfectly capable of this. jQuery will make your life a bit easier should you go that route.

Here's an example of how to show different form options based on a dropdown value using jQuery:

```
<form>
    <div>Are you in school?
        <select id="in_school">
            <option selected="selected">Please choose</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="in_school_yes" class="in_school_input" style="display: none;">
        What grade are you in?
        <input type="text" name="grade" />
    </div>
    <div id="in_school_no" class="in_school_input" style="display: none;">
        What year did you graduate?
        <input type="text" name="graduation_year" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$("#in_school").change(function() {
    var in_school = $(this).val();
    $(".in_school_input").hide("fast", function() {
        $("#in_school_" + in_school).show("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RDtVZ/

Comment: jQuery will make your like a lot easier in this case, it'll take at least 50 lines to do the same thing with pure JS

Comment: Using jQuery you would need to delegate event handlers to allow for future elements using `on()`. Also `$(".in_school_input").hide`  would hide all the inputs of that class in page

Comment: @JuanMendes excluding the animation, this could be done in just a few more lines without jQuery. 50 is a bit much.

Comment: Yes, the animation is the harder part

Answer (score 2):

Knockout can really shine when you are wanting to create complex UIs that need to dynamically change client-side. Here is a simple example of how to do what you are asking in Knockout.

Html:

```
 <form>
     <select name="inputSelect" data-bind="options: dataSet, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedItem,  optionsCaption: '-- Select --'"></select>

     <input type="text" name="firstName" data-bind="value: firstName, visible: selectedItem() && selectedItem().Name == 'First Name'" /> 
     <input type="text" name="lastName" data-bind="value: lastName, visible: selectedItem() && selectedItem().Name == 'Last Name'" /> 
     <input type="text" name="age" data-bind="value: age, visible: selectedItem() && selectedItem().Name == 'Age'" /> 
</form>
```

JS Model:

```
function Model() {
   var self = this;
   self.firstName = ko.observable('Matthew');
   self.lastName = ko.observable('Cox');
   self.age = ko.observable(26);

   self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

   self.dataSet = ko.observableArray([{ Id: 0, Name:'First Name'}, { Id: 1, Name:'Last Name'}, { Id: 2, Name:'Age'}]);
}

var vm = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JmpGD/1/

Explanation:

I put a `visible` binding on each input that checks the Name property of the `selectedItem()` to determine which item should be displayed.

In the jsfiddle I use a slightly different approach to handle `selectedItem()` being null which would cause the `visible` bindings to blow up when attempting to evaluate `selectedItem().Name == 'something'`.

You can read about how that works here

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html

Comment: agreed. KO really does shine with dynamic html.  much clearer and more decoupled than jquery